# FFmpeg resize without upscaling

Tags: ffmpeg

I am working on a script that searches for all media files in the current directory and subdirectories and then batch encodes them to H.265. I was hoping to put in some max frame sizes to make things that are 1080p to be 720p. That is the straightforward part but I have some that are 480p and I don't want those to end up as 720p. How can I modify my ffmpeg filters to take that into account?

The command:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset medium -crf 28 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
-vf "scale=-2:min'(720,ih)'"
```

or

```
-vf "scale=min'(1280,iw)':-2"
```

See :

- [FFmpeg Arithmetic Expression](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) for a list of accepted functions
- [FFmpeg Filters: Scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) for more info on the scale filter